# Creating a 'vocabulary' to group words having same meaning for word frequency

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I have this output from n-grams analysis by using CountVectorizer (texts are stored in pandas dataframe):

```
    Frequency
Words   
playstation 5   106
hours app   32
app store   20
5 playstation   17
hour app    16
... ...
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create a 'vocabulary' of synonymous where I can set:

```
playstation 5 = 5 playstation
```

in order to sum 106 + 17 in the final frequency list.
It is not about lemmatising but rather order. I can do it manually, but I would like to know how to do it.

Many thanks

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the Levenshtein distance to check how closer the two words are like

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

fuzz.token_sort_ratio('playstation 5','5 playstation')
>> 100
fuzz.token_sort_ratio('playstation 5','4 playstation')
>> 92
```

I have used the [fuzzy wuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) python module for this.

Comment: Thank you @Mangy 007. However how could I add these words to a 'vocabulary'? I have thought to group together words having values greater of 90, but it is also true that hours app and hour app could by grouped together. I would like to count together playstation names separately from app

Comment: Hi, I think you can do lemmatization before taking token similarity as hours app will gets converted to hour app, so redundancy won't be there.